# How To Generate Data With Specified Mean Using Python?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I want to generate some linear date with sample size 40 and 2 features. There is a library in python called make_regression, but I want to build it around a specified mean. For example, I want it to create some data where the second feature's(Price) mean is 800. Is it possible?

Comment: You want help mathematically or programmatically?

Comment: We call it random number generation, and it is ubiquitous - please notice that [research is an important first step in solving problems](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/), and some research is certainly expected before rushing to open a question here.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [numpy.random.normal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html):

> Draw random samples from a normal (Gaussian) distribution.

Example:

```py
# SD - Standard deviation
numpy.random.normal(loc=800, scale=SD, size=40)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach :

```
import random 
feature2 = [] 
for i in range(20):
    num = random.randint(10, 500)
    feature2.append(800-num)
    feature2.append(800 + num)
```